# Android Custom Button Ripple/pulse Effect

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view, effects

I have created a custom circular button using the following :

```
    <Button
    android:id ="@+id/StartButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Here button_bg_round is defined as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#3aeaee"/>
        <size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Now, I want to add a circular ripple/pulse  effect/animation when the button is clicked. I tried to look for a possible solution on google and SO but couldn't find any related to such a button. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"> <!-- ripple effect color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#3aeaee"/>
            <size android:width="200dp" android:height="200dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

where android:color inside ripple is the color of the effect.

Comment: Thanks for helping but I tried using this but it created a ripple effect inside the circular button; but i wanted the ripple to be created outside the button. Any help?

Comment: If you wrap the button inside a FrameLayout with the background as the ripple i gave to you and listen the button onclicklistener then you can trigger the FrameLayout.performClick or some method like that.